# SQL for total count and count within that where condition is true

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I have a single user table and I'm trying to come up with a query that returns the total count of all users grouped by date along with the total count of users grouped by date who are of a specific client.

Here is what I have thus far, where there's the total count of users grouped by date, but can't seem to figure out how to get the count of those users where user.client_id = x

```
SELECT user.created,
COUNT(user.id) AS overall_count
FROM user
GROUP BY DATE(user.created)
```

trying for a row result like this:

```
[created] => 2010-05-15 19:59:30
[overall_count] => 10
[client_count] => (some fraction of overall count, the number of users where 
                   user.client_id = x grouped by date)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do the trick for MySQL:

```
SELECT
  user.created,
  COUNT(user.id) AS overall_count,
  SUM(user.client_id = x) AS client_count
FROM user
GROUP BY DATE(user.created)
```

The boolean expression `user.client_id = x` returns `1` if it is true and `0` if not, so you can just sum them up.

---

With another database you would do

```
SUM( CASE WHEN user.client_id = x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS client_count
```